# How to follow the file starting with the end position (tail -fn 0) in Perl

Tags: perl, io

I'd like to do something similar to "tail -fn 0 fileName".
So I need to skip to the end of the file and read only appended lines.

Here's the code for following the file :

```
open(FH,"<" ,"fileName.txt") || die "Can't open file , $!";
for (;;) {
    while (<FH>) {
      #process line 
}
    sleep(1);
    seek(FH, 0, 1);
}
```

I tried to set the position to the end of file before the for loop , but it still reads starting from the beginning.

```
seek(FH , -1 , SEEK_END);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to enable warnings first,

```
use warnings;
```

and import seek constants (`SEEK_END`)

```
use Fcntl qw(:seek);
```

After that

```
seek(FH , -1 , SEEK_END) or warn "Can't seek";
```

will position your handle at one byte before last one, so use `0` instead of `-1` if you wan't to go at the end of the file.

Comment: I added warnings and now I see that SEEK_END was't recognized correctly as a number... , but I was checking the result from seek and it was 1 (so success) ... I'm new to Perl , but shouldn't I get an error if the constant value is undefined ?

Comment: @KatrinnaL you can check actual file position with `tell(FH)` after successful seek. No, you shouldn't get error so warnings are recommended. You can also throw an exception for warnings if that is desired behavior. `$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { die @_ };`